# core-header-panel not visible?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I made a simple example to show a core-header-panel (Polymer web-component) in a webpage. But I don't see anything in the browser and there is also no error in de console (Chrome).

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong? I think I should at least see the text inside the core-header-panel.

The code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
</head>

<body unresolved touch-action="auto" fullbleed vertical layout>

<core-header-panel fit>
<div class="core-header">Welcome</div>
<div class="content">Bla bla bla</div>
</core-header-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `core-header-panel` doesn't have any explicit height so usually you need to tell it to fill its parent. You've done this by using the `fit` attribute on the header panel and `fullbleed` on body (so body is 100% height).

I just tossed your code into jsbin and I see the content of the header panel showing up.
http://jsbin.com/letat/2/edit

Are you on Chrome or perhaps a different browser?

Comment: Fwiw, `flex` is better than `fit` in this situation. Using `layout` attributes all the way down will give more consistent results.

Comment: I see that jsbin does display it correct. But I use Chrome 35. Why does it display correctly in Chrome?

Comment: You post got me thinking about the differences and I tried the imports  to the www.polymer-project.org domain (that you have used on jsbin). Then it start to work. Somehow the problem is in the import for the polymer.html. When I use the local version I run into trouble. The remote version on www.polymer-project.org works. But I have no idea why. It shows that both are version 0.3.3. Only difference that I can find is that the one on www.polymer-project.org is obfuscated.

Comment: I just did a bower cache clean and fresh install of everything and it still seems to work. Maybe try removing all of the layout attributes and just set it up with CSS like this: http://jsbin.com/letat/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your platform.js import is correctly mapped?

I copied your code and I see your two lines but do not see the polymer elements. I'm guessing your platform.js is incorrect.

Comment: It's the other way around. My platform.js is correct. If I remove it from the html, I also the the two lines but not the polymer elements. So I guess you did something wrong.

Comment: My platform.js is pointing to the 0.3.3 version. I believe that is the latest one.